# Dynamic way to set Bounds for JLabel to JPanel in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jlabel

currently I have a set coordinate to pass to setBounds method and the label displays on the bottom, left corner of JPanel correctly.

When I resize the window, the label does not dynamically follow the window but it just stays at the same place.

here is the code example.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel();

label.setText("Dynamic label");

label.setBounds(15, 45, 400, 700);
this.panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
this.panel.setVisible(true);
```

How can I make this label dynamic without changing the panel and the layout type?

Comment: 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. 2) Note that `label.setBounds(15, 45, 400, 700);` will be ignored, given the layout. But *".. the label displays on the bottom, left corner of JPanel correctly."* Adding the label to the `SOUTH` of a `BorderLayout` will have it appear at the bottom, while `label.setText("Dynamic label");` would align the text to the left, It should stay bottom left if the GUI is resized, if it doesn't in the code, it is becaus there are other factors that are ..

Comment: .. not apparent in the code snippet. Best post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I took your advice and set the label to Left and kept the panel to BorderLayout.SOUTH and it works. I don't think I will ever use the setBound method in the future..

Comment: If I were to add multiple buttons (positioned right, bottom) on the same panel with BorderLayout.SOUTH, why does the label get disappeared?

Comment: Only one component can appear in each constraint of a border layout. One way around that is to add a(nother) panel to the south border layout area, then add components to that panel.

Comment: *"How can I make this label dynamic without changing the panel and the layout type?"* - You can't, that's the point of the layout manager, it is responsible for managing the layout of the container